# cant save file in network

Tags: php, network-programming, phpexcel

this is working when i am saving in my local computer, but when i try to save in network it gives me an error.

```
Warning: fopen(\\ipcsvs001\c$\myfolder\12122014.xls) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\receivables\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php on line 90

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Can't open \\ipcsvs001\c$\myfolder\12122014.xls. It may be in use or protected.' in C:\wamp\www\receivables\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php:93 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\receivables\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5.php(226): PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_Root->save('\\ipcsvs001\c...') #1 C:\wamp\www\receivables\index.php(241): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('\\ipcsvs001\c...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\receivables\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php on line 93
```

my code is like this

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5'); 
$objWriter->save('\\\ipcsvs001\c$\myfolder\\'.date('mdY').'.xls');
```

note: i have a full control access in this folder "\ipcsvs001\c$\myfolder\"

TIA for the help guys.

Comment: did you try to write to another location ??

Comment: Try -  fopen("\\ipcsvs001\c$\myfolder\12122014.xls","r")

Comment: i`ve got an error - Warning: fopen(\\ipcsvs001\c$\myfolder\12122014.xls) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\receivables\index.php on line 23

Comment: this -  fopen('\\\ipcsvs001\c$\myfolder\12122014.xls', 'r');

Comment: try -  fopen('/ipcsvs001/c$/myfolder/12122014.xls', 'r');

Comment: `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\receivables\index.php on line 23` - error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your web server has no appropriate rights to write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If your ipcsvs001 is a sub directory from your main php try as follows

```
fopen('..ipcsvs001/c$/myfolder/12122014.xls', 'r');
```

Try these - http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Comment: its not a sub directory ipcsvs001 is another computer in network.

Comment: how to give permission to web server to access a file or folder?

Comment: how to do that in windows 7?